# Relay Replacement (Datasheet Questions)

Tags: power-electronics, solid-state-relay

I need to replace the following relay: 941H-2C-5D
The datasheet can be found here:
https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/Hsin-Da-Precision-941H-2C-5D_C259268.pdf

From what I understand from this datasheet is:

- High Sensitivity
- Coil Nominal Voltage is 5V
- Coil Resistance is 167Ohms
- Pickup Voltage Is 4V
- Dropout Voltage is 0.25
- Nominal Current is 29.9mA

The replacement relay I am looking at is the following:
https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/cit-relay-and-switch/j104d2c5vdc-15s/12503602

This is the .15W model.

From the datasheet I understand the following:

- High Sensitivity
- Rated Coil Voltage is 5V
- Coil Resistance is 167Ohms
- Pickup Voltage is 3.75V
- Release (Dropout Voltage) is 0.5V
- Nominal Current is 29.9mA

This replacement relay should work fine correct? It is switching a low current 24VDC lightstack (LED), that is being switched by 5V coming from a controller.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I already ordered one with a 24VDC coil voltage, but I think that because im using 5V to control it, that is why the relay I just bought is not working.

Please let me know if this new one will work. Thanks.

Comment: It looks like an approximate match, but why it needs to be replaced? If it wore out, the new one will too. If the relay driver won't work, changing the relay does not help. How much is your low current load, as the relay can only handle 2A resistive DC load.

Comment: @Justme The relay needs to be replaced because I broke one of the pins on the package off. The relay driver works fine, I just swapped it with a relay from an identical machine I have. The load is only 0.23mA DC.

Comment: " but I think that because im using 5V to control it, that is why the relay I just bought is not working" So what did you think pickup and dropout voltage meant? https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/256304/what-are-pick-up-dropout-and-rated-voltages-in-a-relay-datasheet

Comment: To be honest the other relay I had purchased was this one:
https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/cit-relay-and-switch/J104D2C24VDC-20S/12503156

Which had a 24V coil voltage, I was not that familiar with relays and was a hasty purchase, got alot going on with this project at the moment and kind of just rushed it. I undersstand that pickup is the minimum for the coil to start switching, and drop out is the voltage it will switch back when it falls under. Correct me if Im wrong, sorry kinda fresh out of school and didnt deal with them alot during my Undergrad lol.